# Delegate not working in singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, singleton

To have a network connection over my multiple view's, I created a Singleton network controller to handle the data between the server and the client. Unfortunately, it is not working because the delegate method is not being called from my singleton to the other view.. Below my code:

** The singleton is the SocketIOConnection.h and .m

```
//
//  SocketIOConnection.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SocketIO.h"
#import "SocketIOPacket.h"

@protocol SocketIOConnectionDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) receivedPacket:(id)packet;
@end

@interface SocketIOConnection : NSObject <SocketIODelegate> {

    SocketIO *IO;
    id <SocketIOConnectionDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SocketIO *IO;
@property (retain) id <SocketIOConnectionDelegate> delegate;


+ (SocketIOConnection *)sharedSingleton;

@end



//
//  SocketIOConnection.m

#import "SocketIOConnection.h"

@implementation SocketIOConnection

@synthesize IO, delegate;

static SocketIOConnection *shared = NULL;

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        IO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        [IO connectToHost:@"domain.com" onPort:443];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (SocketIOConnection *)sharedSingleton
{
    @synchronized(shared)
    {
        if ( !shared || shared == NULL )
        {
            // allocate the shared instance, because it hasn't been done yet
            shared = [[SocketIOConnection alloc] init];
        }

        return shared;
    }
}

-(void)socketIO:(SocketIO *)socket didReceiveEvent:(SocketIOPacket *)packet {
    NSLog(@"Delegating received packet..");
    [delegate receivedPacket:packet.dataAsJSON];
}

@end
```

So this is the code of my singleton, below i will post the code of my viewcontroller.h and .m

```
//
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "SocketIOConnection.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MBProgressHUDDelegate, SocketIOConnectionDelegate>
{
    MBProgressHUD   *HUD;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SocketIOConnection *IOConnection;

@end



//
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
    NSDictionary *operatorData;
}

@synthesize SESSION, IOConnection;

#pragma mark - view Did Load, View Will Appear & didReceiveMemoryWarning

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    IOConnection    = [SocketIOConnection sharedSingleton];

    // fire auth function to verify the operator and sign him in.
    NSMutableDictionary *tokenAndLicense = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [tokenAndLicense setValue:[operatorData objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"__ca.token"];
    [tokenAndLicense setValue:[operatorData objectForKey:@"license"] forKey:@"__ca.license"];
    [IOConnection.IO sendEvent:@"auth" withData:tokenAndLicense];

}

-(void)receivedPacket:(id)packet { <<<< void that should be fired because of the delegate
    NSLog(@"Receive ieks..");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Why is my delegate method not getting called?

Comment: If you're beginner. Always check ARC on and use property(nonotamic,weak) for custom delegate.

Comment: Yes, ARC is on thanks for the tip.

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate?

Comment: @gaige what do you mean? I am creating the delegate in the socketioconnection.h?

Comment: You created the variable, but it is nil, so sending a message to the delegate does nothing.   You need to actually assign the delegate to where you want the messages to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to set the delegate in your code.  You should probalby do this right after you call the singleton in the view controller's `ViewWillAppear`.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    IOConnection    = [SocketIOConnection sharedSingleton];

    IOConnection.delegate = self;

    // fire auth function to verify the operator and sign him in.
    NSMutableDictionary *tokenAndLicense = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [tokenAndLicense setValue:[operatorData objectForKey:@"token"] forKey:@"__ca.token"];
    [tokenAndLicense setValue:[operatorData objectForKey:@"license"] forKey:@"__ca.license"];
    [IOConnection.IO sendEvent:@"auth" withData:tokenAndLicense];

}
```